# Upgrade python 2 to 3.8.8 on suse Linux and Install pip3

Tags: python, sles, pip

I have Python 2.9 on my suse-linux machine (SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP1). I have upgraded it to Python 3.8.8.

When I try to install pip using

```sh
zypper install python3-pip
```

It says python3-pip not found. I am afraid that python3 is not installed properly.

When I run `python3.8 -m test`, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'posix' has no attribute '_all_'
During handling above exception, another exception occured:
SystemError: <built-in function dir> returned NULL without setting an error.
```

Here's how I installed Python 3.8.8, I ran these commands as root:

```sh
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.8/Python-3.8.8.tgz
tar -xvzf Python-3.8.8.tgz
cd Python-3.8.8
./configure
make
make install
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

I have read quite a few questions on Stack Overflow, nothing really helped.

Could someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Anaconda fixed the issue.